# tslint problem when adding typescript to create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, create-react-app

I've tried to add typescript to an existing project so that I can start to learn it. SO far I have zero knowledge of typescript and have run into a problem.

> Cannot find "path_to_project\tslint.json" file. Please check webpack and
>   ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin configuration. Possible errors:
>     - wrong `context` directory in webpack configuration (if `tslint` is not set or is a relative path in fork plugin configuration)
>     - wrong `tslint` path in fork plugin configuration (should be a  relative or absolute path)
>     - `tslint` path is not set to false in fork plugin configuration (if you want to disable tslint support)

I followed the instructions on the create-react-app site by installing the required npm modules and renamed index.js to index.tsx, I also updated react-scripts to react-scripts-tx (which isn't in the instructions but it fixed another error).

I have tried searching my project for "tslint", "ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin" and "webpack" but can't see anywhere to fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be that I was using react-scripts-ts

I didn't realise that this was a 3rd party package which isn't needed if you're using the official solution.